# Master Theorem and exponential functions

Tags: algorithm, recurrence, exponential, big-o, master-theorem

I recently came accross some exercises on the Master Theorem and the sort.
One dictated that we find the Θ() of some expressions (given Τ(1)=Θ(1)).
Most were solved with the Master Theorem, but this one

```
T(n)=T(n^(5/6))+Θ(logn)
```

obviously isn't solved like that, since it's not the generic form of the theorem.
How do we find the Θ() of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can telescope the series to relatively easily find a solution. It's `Theta(log n)` no matter the power in the recurrence relation (assuming it's less than one). Here with `c` instead of 5/6.

```
T(n) = T(n^c) + log n
     = log n + log(n^c) + log(n^(c^2)) + log(n^(c^3)) + ...
     = (1 + c + c^2 + ...)(log n)
     <= (log n)/(1 - c)
```

Trivially `T(n) >= log n`, so `T(n) = Theta(log n)`.

Comment: If you need a rigorous proof you'll have to do it by induction instead of using "...", @Paul's proof is right !